# Storing a function within an object variable

Tags: python, eclipse, function, store

I am beginning python and am working with some considerably complex code, so bear with me if my vocabulary is off.

Using pydev for Eclipse.

I am having difficulty storing a function within a local object variable. The function can be stored in a plain local variable, but if it is attached to the object (self) it will not work.

Basically, I have something like this:   (generalized for example)

```
foo = StackExchange(inputFunction)
```

(the following in a different file, same package)

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self,inputFunction):
        self.function = inputFunction
        self.test = 123
        function = inputFunction
        function2 = lambda x:x**2
        self.function2 = function2
```

above, when looking at the variables in eclipse, `inputFunction` exists and is proper.

`function` gets created and stores `inputFunction`,

but `self` has no `function` or `function2` variable attached to it (i.e. self.function`).

It does have `self.test` (as expected)

Similarly, `function2` gets created and stores the lambda function, but not `self.function2`. I use this example to demonstrate it isn't an issue with `inputFunction` itself.

I have tried, of course, things like:

```
bar = function2
self.function2 = bar
```

but same result.

Not sure if this is an eclipse thing or a python thing in general. As I step through each line of the `__init__` the `self` variable behaves strangely but don't think its worth explaining (but worth mentioning).

Thank you!

EDIT:

After testing with the help of all your replies

I have realised this is a problem with eclipse and or (probably) the PyDev plugin for it.

`print foo.function` DOES return the lambda function even though eclipse does not have a variable `function` appended to the object `foo`. I was mislead.

Why the program fails when it tries to call foo.function must lie within inputFunction itself.
Thank you all very much.

Comment: Could you post a code sample that replicates the problem? I suspect what you've provided here was transcribed from memory, since `Class` with a capital C is a syntax error. In any case, objects can indeed store functions; see [this](http://ideone.com/uIDdwD) sample which prints the value of `StackExchange.function`.

Comment: Class was a typo. I am transcribing from eclipse to here. I come from java, habit.

Comment: You mentioned, "when looking at the variables in eclipse, `inputFunction` exists and is proper". How are you looking at the variables? Outputting them with `print` statements? Or some kind of IDE-specific method, like an expression window or a tooltip over the variable name? Perhaps Eclipse doesn't like to display information about lambdas. Does `bar` exist when you look at it?

Comment: it is IDE specific---there is a variable list in the debug perspective, it will show you variables and their values. I am not printing. Yes, `bar` exists in the list, as does `function2` (both lambdas) but as soon as I append it to `self` it disappears. I suppose it could just be the IDE, I could run some more tests. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Eclipse and pydev, but the following works fine for me:

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self, inputFunction):
        self.function = inputFunction
    def call(self, param):
        return self.function(param)

foo = StackExchange(lambda x: x**2)
print(foo.call(4))
=> 16
```

so `self.function` obviously works correctly, just as in your example.

Comment: I dont know why I cannot reproduce this in my specific case. It seems like I am missing something obvious because it definitely should work. It wouldn't have anything to do with the `inputFunction` being defined in a different file than where the class is?

Comment: If inputFunction was unknown then you'd get an error at `foo = StackExchange(inputFunction)`, so - any error messages?. Also, I suppose you do a `from <Modulename> import inputFunction`?

Comment: just updated my question, appears that it does work properly and it is just a problem within eclipse.  thank you for the feedback. Tony, can u run this in the debugger and see if `self` has the `function` variable underneath?

Comment: I just tried the debugger with it and don't see the function assigned ... but it still works. Pydev perhaps.

Comment: A method of a class needs self passed as its only argument. Could that be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did what uselpa did so here's a different approach to consider.

You assign the method to the Class, every class and every instantiated instance of the class gets the method.  But the method your adding has a 'self' argument ... because methods of a class are suppose to have self aren't they? Hope this helps.

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 123
        function2 = lambda x:x**2
        self.function2 = function2

def afunction(self):
    print 'something'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    beforese = StackExchange()
    if hasattr(beforese,'function'):
        beforese.function()
    else:
        print "beforese doesn't have function"
    StackExchange.function = afunction
    se = StackExchange()
    se.function()
    beforese.function()
```

Comment: I deleted and put 'afunction' in a different file and imported it. from afunctionfile import afunction and it still works.

Comment: Hi Tony, can u run this in the debugger(eclipse) and see if `self` has the `function` variable underneath?

Comment: I did and can't see it but it works.  Is this what you experienced?  Note that a method of a class needs self passed as its only argument even when it has no arguments. Could that be your issue?

Comment: Also I'm really not so sure about the Lambda function as a class attribute (the use of); couldn't you define a method that did X**2? @Tenwest

Comment: So I have the function defined in a different file with a single print statement in it.  I added a breakpoint at that print statement and it hits it, (in addition to printing it) -- but doesn't show up under self as a variable/method.  I also added a simple variable to uselpa's example; it shows up but the methods/functions do not in the debugger under self.

Comment: Sorry Tony I wasn't as clear-----yes it appears the function DOES work as I intended it to and eclipse DOES NOT show it stored, I am getting the same result as you. thank you very much for your help. It was an issue for me because the function was very, very slow and the rest of the program would timeout before the function would finish, and I couldn't even "step in" with eclipse--it was just misleading. Again, thank you!